# Why isn't this allowing me to randomly reaarange a word (string)?

Tags: java, string, character

I'm trying to take a word and randomly scramble it. I'm not exactly sure why this is not working. It's saying 'Cannot resolve method 'setCharAt(int, char)'

I'm not sure what to do here. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String word = scan.next();

        Random ran = new Random();

        StringBuffer newword = new StringBuffer (word);

        int a = ran.nextInt(newword.length());
        int b = ran.nextInt(newword.length());
        char temp;
        temp = newword.charAt(a);
        word.setCharAt(b, newword.charAt(a));






    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as StringBuilder replaced it more than ten years ago.

Answer (score 0):

#### To Shuffle Two Characters

Modify `newword` (not `word`, which is an *immutable* `String`). Also, I would prefer `StringBuilder` to `StringBuffer`. Make sure `a` is not `b`, and also you need to save `b` in `temp` if you want to swap `b` with `a` as posted. Like,

```
StringBuilder newword = new StringBuilder(word);
int a = ran.nextInt(newword.length());
int b = ran.nextInt(newword.length());
while (a == b) {
    b = ran.nextInt(newword.length());
}
char temp = newword.charAt(b);
newword.setCharAt(b, newword.charAt(a));
newword.setCharAt(a, temp);
```

#### The Shuffle All of the Characters

**Alternatively**, you could build a `List<Character>` and *shuffle* that list. Like,

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
    list.add(ch);
}
Collections.shuffle(list, ran); // <-- the default behavior w/o `ran` should suffice,
                                //     Collections.shuffle(list);
StringBuilder newword = new StringBuilder();
for (Character ch : list) {
    newword.append(ch);
}
```